# Parallel ground settings for enable/disable of DC converters

Tags: diodes, ground, converter, schottky

Maybe this is not even that complex but I'm not finding any practical solution right now.

I'm using 6 [Murata DC/DC converters](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807036256286/mysgk02506brsr.pdf?1583754814000) (labelled with CH1 to CH6). I want to use the enabling pin of those converters to enable/disable them on command.

To achieve this I need to use two separate systems, one hardwired circuit called LV Reset and a software controlled one from a microcontroller.

In the normal state those circuit outputs are floating or high, and when I want to reset the converters the LV Reset Input (called LV_Reset_enable) or pin of the microcontroller (called Restart_CHX) are set to ground. The EN_CH1 from the schematic goes directly to the enable pin of the converter. Ignore the solder pads, they are just for future design changes.

[image: Enabling config]

My only problem now is that I want to use both systems without them interfering with each other. So when I pull to microcontroller pin (Restart_CHX) to ground I don't want the LV_Reset_enable also set to ground. I tried to do this with an Schottky diode (like in the schematic), but I noticed from the Murata datasheet that the ground potential needs to be below 0.1 V and the Schottky diode has a forward voltage drop of 0.3 V so it wouldn't turn the converter off.

Any ideas? I'm currently in my third semester EE so treat me gently ;)

Comment: What are the signal voltages involved?  You could just use OR gates to drive the EN/UVLO pin.

Comment: @vir the microcontroller is 3.3V and the lv reset in normal state roughly about 4V (although I could change this quite easily to maybe also 3.3V) => so OR gates ain't a bad idea